# could not reslove 'packages.ros.org.ros'

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, ros

I have recently installed Ubuntu version 16.04 and trying to install ROS kinetic on my laptop. However, I got stuck at this point where after running `sudo apt-get update`.

This is the result:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org.ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org.ros'
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org.ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org.ros'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have searched for a solution online for quite awhile now, but still cannot seem to solve the issue.

Comment: If I open those links in a browser, I get '*site cannot be reached*'.  I don't know what the site is, or why you added it, but did you verify it's still there?  or should it have been `http://packages.ros.org/ros/`  ?? (that works, and does support xenial/16.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have made a typo

replace your http://packages.ros.org.ros/ubuntu  with http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/

as that actually gives me Oregon State University's Open Source Lab, which is I suspect what you're after.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! However, after the correction

Err:1 http://packages.ros.org.ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org.ros'
.
. (Get some extra ...)
.


Fetched 5.223 kB in 7s (674 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org.ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org.ros'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Still not able to fetch the files. I am so sorry.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, and leave me a comment to look there (formatting options are limited & detail hard to read in comments; we can help you to correct formatting in questions & answers). The error message contains the same wrong/typo http://packages.ros.org.ros/ link which needs correction to http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ as mentioned.  You possibly didn't save your correction?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, indeed the correction was not saved. It worked. 

Thank you so much.